# Globally override dependent on packages

Tags: node.js, alias, npm-package

I'm attempting to override a package like so:

```
"@thirdparty/sdk": "npm:@MyPackage/sdk",
```

However I'm running into issues as there are other npm packages who internally are dependent on  `@thirdparty/sdk`

Is there a way to globally apply this alias to the package dependencies as well?